# Создание treeview в android (подчинение)

Tags: java, android

такой вопрос, необходимо сделать что-то в этом роде:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е дерево с тонкими линиями, находил в сети библиотеки но все не то.
В какую сторону копать?

Comment: Я бы покопал в сторону Material Design. Как мне кажется можно сделать красивее в виде табличек, используя CardView. Делал подобное в своем приложении в комментариях. Выглядит очень минималистчино и красиво. Плюс не нужно никаких сторонних библиотек.

Comment: @Arnis Shaykh
знаю,но нужно именно линиями

Comment: Тогда можно сделать свою кастомную вьюху. Я не думаю что где то можно найти что то похожее. По сути это вложенные вьхи плюс линии.

Comment: @ Arnis Shaykh
а алгорит то какой?
линии как рисовать то? 
в плане подчинения, от объекта а к б

Comment: На счет линий не уверен, надо подумать. На счет подчинения я сделал следующим образом: обьект в списке дерева хранит ссылку на своего родителя на уровень выше и свою позицию на текущем уровне. Таким образом в плане подчинения и навигации у меня все работает хорошо.

Comment: актуально, может есть еще варианты?